# Creating feature with cross features inside my sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to create a new feature which is based on the calculation of other two features from my dataset with a [`FunctionTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html) probably from sklearn to include it inside a `Pipeline`. for example if i have `feature_1` and `feature_2` and i want to create `feature_3` which is substraction of one over the other ( `feature_3` = `feature_1` - `feature_2` ).

if my df looks like this

```
df
feature_1  feature_2
        2          1
        3          2
```

needed to create preprocessor which does `feature_1` - `feature_2` inside.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't [show](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) us your callable.

---

Clearly you could synthesize a delta feature beforehand:

```
df['feature_3'] = df.feature_1 - df.feature_2
```

But it appears you want to do it as a transformer, fine.

---

You're having trouble understanding / debugging
the calling sequence, despite this example from the docs:

> transformer = FunctionTransformer(np.log1p)
> X = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
> transformer.transform(X)

Ok.
Here's a generic approach to figuring out callbacks.
Don't bother computing a delta,
just stick to debug output for now.

```
def delta(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
    breakpoint()
```

Use *that* in your pipeline
and you'll see exactly how the callable is being called.
Feel free to interrogate the `type( ... )` of specific
arguments, or use `pprint.pp( ... )` to format them.

Once you have a good feel for how you're being called,
you'll be in a better position to accept args of
expected type and do the right computation with them.